# Store time in local system and compare it with current time in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have `start_time : 17:00:00` and `end_time : 18:00:00` in database user is allowed to make calls between this time only.

I'm fetching this time from server and store it in local variable

```
      var start_time='';
      var end_time='';
      const results = await fetch(Url+'details', {
            method: 'POST',
            ..
          })
        });
```

results contains `results.start_time` and `results.end_time`

every minute i have to check whether current time lies between the above start_time and end_time i.e. `17:00:00` and `18:00:00` respectively, and call disconnect function to disconnect the call automatically.

If i compare time from server by calling function every minute it may slow down application is there any other way to achieve the same.

Any solution will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: On server check if current time lies between this range and return true or false accordingly.

Comment: @nice_dev checking time every minute will slow down the application in 1 hrs call ?

Comment: So you are fetching details every minute from the server? What are these details?

Comment: @nice_dev In my application one user can connect with other through video call or audio call but it is for limited time for which user has booked once the time is over i want to disconnect it for that i have to compare the time to the booking `start_time` and `end_time`, for eg if user has booked for 17:00:00 to 18:00:00 as soon as time is 18:01:00 call should disconnect, for disconnect i have to call simple function but i have doubt in time compare logic

Comment: [`Long polling`](https://javascript.info/long-polling) seems succinct. You can also lookup for Server sent events and socket connections on the web.

Answer (score -2):

On the server you can change variable connect in the database in specific time with crontab for example. Eg 17:00 change variable to true and 18 00 change to false and in every connection from frontend when user try calling check this variable